# Computing $E[X 1_{ \{ |Y|<1 \}}]$

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Am looking for any suggestions on how to compute
\begin{align*}
E[X \ 1_{ \{ |Y|<1 \}}]
\end{align*}

where $X$ and $Y$ are finite variance random variable assume zero mean.

In my setting $Y=X+W$ where $X$ and $W$ are independent.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Ok. Added more info. Please let me know what else to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat open question, but I will give one possible approach.

My suggestion is to use the law of iterated expectations:

$$E[X1_{\{|Y|<1\}}] = E[E[X1_{\{|Y|<1\}}|Y]]=E[1_{\{|Y|<1\}}E[X|Y]],$$

where I condition on $Y$ and can move the indicator function outside of the inner expectation, since $1_{\{|Y|<1\}}$ is $Y$-measurable. Now notice that you need only calculate the expectation of $X$ conditional on $Y$, say $g(Y)=E[X|Y]$, and you are left with the expectation $E[1_{\{|Y|<1\}}g(Y)]$ involving only the random variable $Y$, which is given by
$$E[1_{\{|Y|<1\}}g(Y)] = \int 1_{\{|y|<1\}}g(y)\text{d}F_Y(y)=\int_{-1}^1 g(y)\text{d}F_Y(y),$$
where $F_Y$ is the distribution function of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would it help if I sad that we can take $W$ to be Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, it might help you when calculating $E[X|Y]$. If you prefer, you can substitute $Y-W$ for $X$, so that $E[X|Y] = E[Y|Y] - E[W|Y] = Y-E[W|Y]$, and you might have an easier handle on the last conditional expectation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one more question. If the distribution of $X$ is symmetric around $0$ and $W$ is Gaussian $0$ mean. Then integral you have is $0$, correct?

Comment: Actually, maybe not.